# custom threads in my code?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I need to create a program scraping a website.
And I did use Thread to solve.

Example:

I have 100 pages and I need divide it, instead of get each page I need custom Thread number to get page:

```
    2 threads - 50 pages/thread

    4 threads - 25 pages/thread
```

I tried my code below, however when to the last page of each thread that very slow.

Before I ask I used to find the way to solve but I can't, therefore I need help.

```
int so_thread = 10;//thread number
int page_du = 0;
List<NameValueCollection> List_item = new List<NameValueCollection>();

Thread[] threads = new Thread[so_thread];
int dem = 0;

await Task.Run(() =>
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= so_thread; i++)
    {
        if ((Int32.Parse(o_sopage.Text) % so_thread) != 0 && i == so_thread)
        {
            page_du = Int32.Parse(o_sopage.Text) % so_thread;//Int32.Parse(o_sopage.Text) == page number need get
        }

        threads[i - 1] = new Thread((object data) =>
        {
            Array New_Data = new object[2];
            New_Data = (Array)data;
            int _i = (int)New_Data.GetValue(0);
            int _pagedu = (int)New_Data.GetValue(1);
            int page_per_thread = Int32.Parse(o_sopage.Text) / so_thread;//Int32.Parse(o_sopage.Text) == page number need get

            for (int j = ((page_per_thread * _i) - page_per_thread) + 1; j <= ((page_per_thread * _i) + _pagedu); j++)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(j.ToString());
                var TG = ebay.GetPage(j);
                lock (List_item)
                {
                    List_item.AddRange(TG);
                    dem++;
                    progressBar1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        progressBar1.Value = dem;
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        object DATA = new object[2] { i, page_du };
        threads[i - 1].Start(DATA);
    }
});
```

Comment: All threads will be 'fighting' for IO and CPU access . Other than that all 4 threads are accessing the UI (List_item) that should be done on the UI thread.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd How do you know what `List_item` is? Seems like just a `List`.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd thanks you , i did run my code and it well done until last item of each thread then very slow . Do you have another idea?

Comment: @Rotem Yes, List_item is a List . I implemented !

Comment: How did you implement the List?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd In my code !!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Parallel.ForEach` instead of creating the threads on your own.

```
Parallel.ForEach(yourCollection, () => { /* your code here */});
```